# Can't install software or perform Windows Updates

Tags: windows-vista, updates, installer

For the last long while Windows Update has been failing on 99% of updates and (certain) software won't install. I have seen the error 0x8007010B in both cases. Why is this happening? How can it be fixed? I've searched all over for answers but I haven't gotten anywhere. I am using 32-bit Vista SP2.

**Update:**
I found this really helpful looking page http://support.microsoft.com/fixit/ and downloaded a thing to fix windows updates and it said it found an issue where the location for updates had been changed and it said it fixed it but updates still don't work.

Comment: What have you tried? You say you've searched all over for answers, so there must be a long list of what you've done.

Comment: It will worth to tell what you have tried for us and you too that to post the same answer which you have already tried.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything because I haven't found any answers. I tried booting with the Windows disk and doing a repair but that did nothing. I had a similar problem before when I tried moving the TEMP and TMP directories to another disk and I fixed it by restoring the default environment variables and this time it seemed like they disappeared again (isn't there supposed to be TEMP and TMP in the User env vars?), but restoring them this time hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: Reboot and run it again. If no issues pop up try downloading the updates again.

Comment: I have rebooted. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The error, 0x8007010B, is caused by the file directory being invalid. Locate and download the update or updates directly from [Microsoft's Download Center](http://bit.ly/qxRoBL). After you download the update or updates follow the steps below. (*Credit: [MowGreen's Post](http://bit.ly/nrnd3R)*)

#### Perform a clean boot of the computer and then install the update

To manually perform a clean boot of your computer in Windows 2000, Windows XP, or Windows   Server 2003, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, click Run, type msconfig, and then click OK.
2. On the General tab, click Selective Startup, and then click to clear the following       check boxes:

   - Process SYSTEM.INI File
   - Process WIN.INI File
   - Load Startup Items
3. On the Services tab, click to select the Hide All Microsoft Services check box, and then click Disable All.
4. Click OK, and then click Restart to restart your computer.
5. Run Microsoft Update or Windows Update. If the update does not run successfully, go to Method 4.

*Note: You'll find more information on this topic and the source at this [Microsoft Support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883825).*

Comment: What directory is invalid? Shouldn't the fix be to correct the "invalid directory"? I don't understand your instructions. I should download and install all 40 updates manually? Why would that work when I can't install other software manually? And then why am I doing a clean boot and running WU if I already installed the updates? What does "go to Method 4" mean? Do these instructions apply to Vista?...

Comment: You can find the updates that causes the problem by: Open the **Windows Update** windows, click *View update history*, review the updates with *Fail* as the status. Once you find the failed update, search for the update on the *MS's Download Center. All Windows update names start with KB for by numbers (e.g. KB2503665).

Answer (score 0):

`Error 0X8007010b` is caused by damaged windows files or broken system structures. This is a critical problem that can cause an unstable operating system, which is typically caused by improper management of the computer.

Use [Windows Repair tool](http://simple-pc-help.com/download/repair-tool.php) to diagnose and fix the cause of your problem.

`1: Download and install the tool.

2: Open it and scan the PC for problems.

3: Click on fix all Button.`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: [Marki](http://superuser.com/users/28469/marki) Warns: I would be careful about any such tools claiming to magically repair the machine. If any, I would download only fixes from Microsoft themselves.

Comment: @Brian Odeja I appreciate  and try to another fix for this. By the way what a coincidence from yesterday we are at the same place.:)

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure if I want to run that.